# How to call functions from variable names

Tags: python, function, call

I have the following file structure:

```
main.py
commands
  | __init.py__
  | a.py
  | b.py
```

In my `__init__.py` I have the following code to be able to dynamically import everything from the commands folder:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

with `from commands import *` in `main.py`,

and inside `a.py` and `b.py` I have the following:

```
def foo():
  return "bar"
```

I want to be able to call on `foo()` in either `a` or `b` from a variable, sort of like `x = commands.{input()}.foo()`, however I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
from commands.a import foo as foo_a
from commands.b import foo as foo_b

foo_a()

foo_b()
```

Comment: except I need to be able to call `foo_a()` from a variable, and I'd prefer if I can import the functions dynamically, so I don't have to add more import's every time I add a new function in the commands folder

Comment: For foo to be called a like `my_variable.foo()` it would have to assigned as a  method of the class of which `my_variable` is an instance.